# What happened to Dr. Carol Marcus in Star Trek Beyond?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness, star-trek-reboot, star-trek-beyond

[Dr. Carol Marcus](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Carol_Marcus_(alternate_reality)) was one of Star Trek Into Darkness's main supporting characters. At the end of the film she's shown to have joined the Enterprise crew and presumably will be setting off with them on their 5-year voyage into the unknown, *to seek out new life, to boldy blah de blah blah.*

[image]

**So where is she in Star Trek Beyond?**

Comment: Drive-by downvoters. I will find you and I will ***destroy*** you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The film's screenwriter Simon Pegg confirmed in an interview that her character is alive and well during the events of Star Trek Beyond, but that she's not on board the Enterprise. She's just...err...*elsewhere.*

> “With this it felt like we would under-serve her if we included her,
> she might end up feeling like she hadn’t been given the amount of
> screen-time she deserves, so rather than bring her in and just have
> her be a supporting role, like, have her not be in this one, and when
> the time comes [bring her back], the worst thing to do would be to
> have her in the film and have that character be killed, and that felt
> like a cynical thing to do. We thought rather than have Carol Marcus
> not be used to a reasonable capacity, **let’s just not include her, have
> her be alive, in canon, and ready to come back at any time.”**
>
> <sub><sup>[Remember Carol Marcus? Simon Pegg Explains Why the Alice Eve Character Wasn’t in Star Trek Beyond](http://www.themarysue.com/what-happened-to-carol-marcus-star-trek-beyond/)</sup></sub>

**So what was she doing?**

The short answer is that she was off doing precisely what she was doing at this point in the prime timeline, developing the [Genesis Project](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Genesis_Device).

> I think we had some lines to explain her absence in one of the initial
> drafts that had her going off to start work on the Genesis project and
> do sort of very, very early research on that. But it didn't make it
> into the final cut.
>
> <sub><sup>[Why Star Trek Beyond Didn’t Include Carol Marcus](http://www.cinemablend.com/news/1541660/why-star-trek-beyond-didnt-include-carol-marcus)</sup></sub>

Comment: If referring to the prime timeline - wouldn't she raise Kirk's son?

Comment: Well, we don't know why she quit the Enterprise :-)

Comment: It would be... interesting if Carol Marcus, an expert in *weapon technology* ran off to develop Genesis.  Recall, in the prime universe, Genesis was meant to create life, not destroy it. Marcus gought against using it as a weapon.

Comment: @dhydar - That's a good point. Since she won't appear in the next film, it's something of a moot point.

Comment: I think Carol transitioning from weapons to Genesis fits perfectly. She _was_ a weapons expert, but the whole thing with her father convinces her to shift careers. Genesis would be a natural transition: able to make use of her expertise in things like torpedoes and explosive energy, but in a more peaceful way.